# Top level Pages redirecting to homepage!

Tags: permalinks, redirect, homepage

For some reason after setting the permalink to any other structure apart from default. The top level pages will start redirecting to the home page. 
I have disabled all the plugins and change theme to any other themes. Same result!

I have noticed similar issue happens to other before, but never a clear answer on how to resolve this.

Any idea??

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that, I was using "year" as a custom taxonomy, which was part of the reserved terms of Wordpress!!! With using the reserved term, it will return the 404 error for the top level pages, hence the redirection to the home page. !!!

Listed here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Comment: Thanks seriously. This cancerous issue was bothering me for 2 days.